# Pass JavaScript date to C# Web API string property

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

When I pass a JavaScript date to a C# Web API controller string property, it gets converted to ISO 8601 UTC format i.e. "2019-08-20T08:30:50Z". I need it to be in my local date format, i.e. "2019-08-20T10:30:50+02:00". I do not want to convert the date on the UI side to a string before it gets passed through or the string in the back end afterwards. I want it to correctly convert automatically when it gets passed through. Is there maybe a setting somewhere that determines this? An attribute or something? Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `2019-08-20T08:30:50Z` and `2019-08-20T10:30:50+02:00` represent the same point in time and are effectively identical

Comment: Yes, but the utc format gives problems when I do reporting.

Comment: Then that's a problem with the reporting. Never store it as a string, then you can format it how you want. Formatting of dates is presentation logic and should always be done as close to the client as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Do the following in your WebApiConfig.cs :

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
```

Comment: This assumes that the client timezone and the server timezone are the same.

Comment: Thanks phuzi. If that was not the case, how would I modify my code?

Comment: Keep dates as dates, never store a date as a formatted string. Storing dates as a UTC Date/Time avoids the complication (a lot of the time) of transalting between different timezones.